# Can Winston Logger be used on the front-end for logging?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, winston

I am creating full mean stack app with

> NodeJs , Angular 6 , ExpressJs and MongoDB

I have managed to create a server and its working perfectly, instead of using `console.log` when logging errors in my app I have decided to use `Winston Logger` here is what I have now

> Server side

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var winston = require('winston');

// define the custom settings for each transport (file, console)
var options = {
    file: {
        level: 'info',
        filename: `${appRoot}/logs/app.log`,
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: true,
        maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
        maxFiles: 5,
        colorize: false,
    },
    console: {
        level: 'debug',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        colorize: true,
    },
};

// instantiate a new Winston Logger with the settings defined above
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.file),
        new winston.transports.Console(options.console)
    ],
    exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});

// create a stream object with a 'write' function that will be used by `morgan`
logger.stream = {
    write: function (message, encoding) {
        // use the 'info' log level so the output will be picked up by both transports (file and console)
        logger.info(message);
    },
};

module.exports = logger;
```

***Note: Winston in server side works perfectly***

> Client-Side

I want to use winston in my client side angular 6 app .

Example: in one of my components i have this.

```
import * as logger from "winston";
.........
 this.activeRouter.params.subscribe((params) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
      let id = params['id'];
      this.moviesService.getReview(id)
        .subscribe(review => {
          console.log(review);
          this.review = review;
        });
    });
```

As you can see I am using `console.log(review)` , Instead of console log I would like to use `Winston` .

How to use `Winston logger` in client-side ?  am newbie to all this stuff any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah it is possible, however default transport for browser is very limited. I recommend to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-transport-browserconsole

`npm install winston-transport-browserconsole -S`

It is easy to use and supports logging json objects:

```
import * as winston from "winston";
import BrowserConsole from 'winston-transport-browserconsole';

const level = "debug";
winston.configure({
    transports: [
        new BrowserConsole(
            {
                format: winston.format.simple(),
                level,
            },
        ),
    ],
});

winston.debug("DEBUG ", {a: 1, b: "two"});
```

Comment: Where can I find examples on how to use them? How for example I set up a transport to a file if I want to log to a persistent file? or to a remote location like a DB?

Answer (score 8):

Yes - it can (technically) be used in the browser. Should it be? Almost definitely not (sadly). Winston is a fantastic logger for node. But, emphasis on "for node". If you want to use it on the client, you would need to add a bunch of node polyfills in addition to winston itself, which is very large relative to other client loggers. Between winston and those polyfills you are going to significantly increase the size of your artifact. Also, just fyi webpack 5 removed those node polyfills, so you would need to add them back manually.

Answer (score 0):

According to this ticket: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/287 it's almost ready for browser use? Or mostly ready? It sounds like they recently started supporting logging in a browser environment.